# list of json object prints the last element several times

Tags: json, ajax, hibernate, spring-mvc

guys i have 2 tables "employee" which has EMPID, EMPAGE, ADDRESS, SALARY, EMPNAME, department_id (foreign key refrences to table "department") and "department" table which has department_id, name ... and i want to put the data via in JSON object and sends it to ajax request ... here is my code

```
public void listDepartment(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, JSONException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    List<JSONObject> arrayFinal = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

    for(int index = 0; index<listDepartment().size(); index++){
        obj1.put("Department ID ",listDepartment().get(index).getDepId());
        obj1.put("Department Name ",listDepartment().get(index).getDepName());

        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        for(Employee l : listDepartment().get(index).getEmployees()){
            array.add("Id= "+l.getEmpId()+" Age= "+l.getEmpAge()+" Salary= "+l.getSalary()+" Address= "+l.getEmpAddress());
            obj1.put("Employees ", array);
        }
        arrayFinal.add(index, obj1);
    }   
    System.out.println(arrayFinal);
    obj.put("MyListDep", arrayFinal);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    out.write(obj.toString());
    out.close();
}
```

so the arrayFinal is printing the last row 5 times instead of printing all the 5 rows ...any help ???

Comment: Please click to chat about the issue http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108707/json-help

Comment: it says i must have 20 rep.

Comment: do you know about jackson?

Comment: ok ... arrayFinal only has copies of the last row only and i am not making anything static .. any suggestions ??

Comment: the business requirements says not to use the jackson

Comment: ok. looking at your code to figure what might be wrong

Comment: i think as per your code you are replacing the contents of your json object. try exiting out of the loop after adding one department, you should be able to see the first.

Comment: yes it replaces all the preceding indexes

Comment: so what should i do ???

Comment: try having new JSONObject(); inside the for loop for obj1

Comment: edited your code to reflect the change

Comment: Sorry removed obj from the code bychance, please make sure you add it back

Comment: Were you able to get it working